# How does python prevent a class from being subclassed?

Tags: python, subclass, final

I came across the following in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool):

> **bool([x])**
>
> Convert a value to a Boolean, using the standard truth testing procedure. If x is false or omitted, this returns False; otherwise it
>   returns True. bool is also a class, which is a subclass of int. **Class
>   bool cannot be subclassed further.** Its only instances are False and
>   True.

I've never in my life wanted to subclass `bool`, but naturally I immediately tried it, and sure enough:

```
>>> class Bool(bool):
    pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    class Bool(bool):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'bool' is not an acceptable base type
```

So, the question: How is this done? And can I apply the same technique (or a different one) to mark my own classes as `final`, i.e., to keep them from being subclassed?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to subclass `bool`? You could create `10` subclasses to represent each possible boolean state.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, that does look like a closely related question. It didn't come up during my SO search (I should have thought to add "final" to the search terms).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `bool` type is defined in C, and its `tp_flags` slot deliberately does not include the [`Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE).

C types need to mark themselves *explicitly* as subclassable.

To do this for custom Python classes, use a metaclass:

```
class Final(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        for b in bases:
            if isinstance(b, Final):
                raise TypeError("type '{0}' is not an acceptable base type".format(b.__name__))
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = Final

class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

gives:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __new__
TypeError: type 'Foo' is not an acceptable base type
```

Comment: On further reflection, I have a question: Is there any purpose to the check `isinstance(b, Final)`? I mean, this `__new__` will only ever be called by a class that inherits from `Final`, so why not just raise immediately if `cls != 'Final'`?

Comment: @alexis: Yes, because you need to name which baseclass it is you tried to inherit from. `Bar` does not subclass `Final`, it subclasses `Foo`, which is why the `isinstance(b, Final)` test returns `True` for that class. If there are more base classes used, you want to tell the end user which one of those bases is not inheritable from.

Comment: Got it, right, it's in a metaclass, not the final class itself. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that this is only to be used for the sake of understanding how Python works. Noone should ever build things like that in a real program.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters! I actually had the problem in PySide2 when converting it to heaptypes (I'm working on PEP 384 support). I could not remove the Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE flag and modified instead the metatype to do the above check in C.