# pep8 minor annoyance

Tags: python, boolean, pep8

In `/tmp/spam.py`:

```
n = 69

if n == True:
    print 'potato'
```

pep8 utility complains about this conditional:

```
wim@SDFA100461C:/tmp$ pep8 spam.py 
spam.py:3:6: E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'
```

- the first suggestion is wrong/"worse" according to [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) itself
- the second suggestion changes the behaviour of the code

What is the best practice for a case where you actually *do* want to check equality with `True`?  Is identity checking with `True` using `is` OK?  Why does pep8 utility offer an alternative which is explicitly discouraged in pep8 itself?

Comment: Why would you check an integer variable, to see if it's a boolean?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly test for `True` values? If you **do** have to test for `True` **only**, then use `is True`.

Comment: FWIW, PEP 8 does say "Don't compare boolean values to True or False[...]", and what you have isn't a boolean value. Although... yeah, it's a bit odd that the tool suggests `is` when the PEP says it's worse. Your last question should probably be asked of the developer of the tool, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really do need to check *equality* with `True` then use `==` and ignore PEP8, but in almost any conceivable case that isn't what you want.

If you want to know whether the value you have is one of the values Python considers to be true, use `if cond:`. If you want to know whether the value you have is the singleton value `True` then use `is True`, the booleans `True` and `False` are singletons so it is correct to use `is` in this situation.

If you need to test whether your object is the singleton `True`, but a linter or a code reviewer complains about `is True`, then `isinstance(x, bool) and x` is a behaviorally equivalent (but slower) substitute.

Checking `x == True` is a halfway house. It is true when `x is True` is true, and false for your case of `x=69`, but there are other objects which are not themselves `True` but for which `x==True` gives an unexpectedly true result such as `1 == True` being true. (thanks @Ant).

So putting that together:

```
value of n:    True  1     69     False   0
-----------------------------------------------
expression     result
-----------------------------------------------
if n:          True  True  True   False   False
if n is True:  True  False False  False   False
if n==True:    True  True  False  False   False
```

Pick the row from that table which gives the results you really wanted (and the last one isn't it).

Comment: 1 == True is True while 69 == True is False

Comment: Remember that `False == 0` and `True == 1` because `issubtype(bool, int)` is true..

Comment: Thanks @Ant, that was the example my explanation was missing.

Comment: Also note that in Python 2, `True` and `False` are variables that can be assigned to (unlike `None`).  This was changed in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, I think a comment is required since the code looks funny.

If you want to check equality with `True` then it might be clearer to write `if n == 1`. Someone reading the code is less likely to misinterpret it as an attempt to test logical truth.

Of course if `n` has a user-defined type it's *possible* to define `n.__eq__` such that `(n == True) != (n == 1)`, but it would be pretty nasty. So you'd have to decide whether the subtle difference in meaning is justified by the benefit of avoiding the code looking like an incorrect logical truth test.

If the difference is not justified, and if you're absolutely required to write to the PEP8 style guide, then either use `assertEqual` or write `expected_value = True`, `if n == expected_value`.

If the code is a unit test for an API that for some reason defines specifically that the literal `True` is returned, then of course you should test `if n is True`, not `if n == True`. As before, a comment or some indirection would be needed to stop the code looking wrong.

Another option is to change the API you're testing. The reason for the style guide rules is in part to discourage people from inventing or relying on APIs that specifically define that the return value must be identical or equal to the literal `True`, and instead define APIs and write their code in terms of logical truth. So if you "fix" the API you can "fix" the code that tests it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to explicitly test for `True` values? You rarely, if ever do need narrow your test down to a specific type. I'd rethink your use case here; if you are building an API that'll return a `bool` instead of in `int` for out-of-band conditions, then use exceptions instead.

If you **do** have to test for `True` **only**, then use

```
if n is True:
```

because the boolean values are meant to be singletons like `None`. See the [Programming recommendations section](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

Moreover, because `issubtype(bool, int)` is true (for historical reasons; `bool` was introduced rather late in Python), `n == True` is also true for `n = 1`, if you can only accept `True` here then you can only use `is True`. You could also use `isinstance(n, bool) and n`, which would allow for subclasses of `bool`, but I cannot imagine there ever be a use for such a type, and in current implementations, [`bool` explicitly prohibits being subclassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172189/why-i-cant-extend-bool-in-python).

The PEP 8 rule about using not using `if cond is True:` is specifically called out **because** it limits the value of `cond` to the `bool` only.

Last but not least, PEP 8 [starts with this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds):

> #### A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds
>
> [...] But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best.

Only follow PEP 8 if it suits your needs.

Comment: I don't feel like digging up the mailing list message at the moment, but Guido has specifically rejected this construction (in the context of a request to remove the prohibition from PEP 8). His suggestion was `x and isinstance(x, bool)`, which a further caveat that if you're writing this code the API that gave you `x` is horrible and you should fix that instead.

Comment: @Wooble: I find that to be worse; is the expectation that there will be more than *one* copy of `True`? Python 3 made `True` and `False` keywords so you cannot assign other values to the two names, further cementing the fact that they are singletons.

Comment: @Wooble: ah, I suppose you could *subclass* `bool` and provide more values. I find the suggestion that a `bool` subclass could be useful somewhat unlikely; better fix the API that produced that idea..

Comment: That's not the rationale. `if x is True:` is guaranteed to work correctly in the language specification. The reason it's bad style is that when anyone writes that it's nearly always a bug, and someone writing the code may assume they meant `if x:` and then "fix" it. I'm not sure this is actually a good justification for forbidding it (any more than I'm sure about not allowing assignment in a conditional because people frequently mix up `=` and `==` in languages where it's allowed), but, as you say, it's a style guide and if you're not writing for the stdlib ignore it. :)

Comment: For context, I came across this during unit testing of an API where some code is supposed to return the literal `True` and this is being checked with `==`

Comment: @wim: in that case assert that the type returned is `bool` and be done with it. `assertTrue(n)` and `assertTrue(isinstance(n, bool))`.

Comment: OK.  Are True and False singletons in both python 2 and 3, out of interest?

Comment: @wim: the [datamodel](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) documents them as such.

Comment: @wim: And in Python 3, [`True`, `False` and `None` became reserved keywords](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax) to further protect their singleton status. In Python 2, you can still do `True = 1` and get away with it, mostly.

Comment: @wim: But if you came across it in a unittest, why wasn't that test using `self.assertEqual(n, True)` instead of `n == True`?

Comment: You can't actually subclass `bool` (at least in CPython - I don't know about other implementations). It's not flagged as an acceptable base type, and you'll get a TypeError if you try.

Comment: @user2357112: ah, yes, of course, and [I knew that already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056691/100297), but I've made it explicit in my answer now too.

Answer (score -2):

The second recommendation would best suit your needs. The conditional statement `if cond:` will return true if the condition itself is true. It will not change the behavior of the code, as it is just shorthand for `if cond == True:`.

Comment: `cond = 2` -> now there's a difference between `if cond:` and `if cond == True:`.