# Reason why xrange is not inheritable in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror, xrange

I was trying to inherit `xrange` (to implement membership testing with `in`, as well as iteration). But I got the following error message:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'xrange' is not an acceptable base type
```

What's special about `xrange`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056574/how-does-python-prevent-a-class-from-being-subclassed/

Comment: FYI, you get similar error when trying subclass `bool`, `slice` or `buffer`.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed

Comment: Note that the `range` type in Python 3.x already implements the behaviours that OP wanted - but is still not inheritable, so the question is not really version-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xrange` is [implemented in C](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange). As you can see in [Tim Peters' post](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/033r5nks47/type-function-does-not-subtype#20030324rcnwbkfedhzbaf3vmiuer3z4xq), there should be a convincing use case in order to justify the extra effort needed to allow subclassing of it.